# Accessing the Options of the parent Cell

Tags: front-end, notebooks

From within the Kernel, it is possible to access a `Cell`'s options using [`CurrentValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CurrentValue.html). For instance, in a `Cell` tagged `{"Bob", "Frank"}`, executing this

```
CurrentValue[CellTags]
(* {"Bob", "Frank"} *)
```

But, how would one go about accessing the options of the parent cell in the hierarchy?

One difficulty is that the `Cell` knows nothing about the `CellGroup` it finds itself in, so attacking the problem from that direction seems difficult. However, the current executing `Notebook` can be accessed via [`EvaluationNotebook`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EvaluationNotebook.html), so traversing the tree from that direction seems plausible, if not efficient.

Comment: Do cell groups have options? Or you meant an inline cell executing in place accesing the containing cell's options?

Comment: @Rojo not as I understand it. Running `NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]]` shows the structure `Cell[CellGroupData[{Cell[...], Cell[CellGroupData[...]]..},Open]]` where the first `Cell` is the parent, and the subsequent ones are the child groups. The cells containing `CellGroupData` do not appear to have any options set, they just provide structure and probably formatting.

Comment: but try to write somehow a cell group with options set. I haven't succeeded so far. The first cell in the cell group seems to get all the options. `NotebookPut@ Notebook@List@Cell[CellGroupData[{Cell["a"], Cell["b"]}], FontWeight->"Bold"]`

Comment: @Rojo right, that's why it is the parent `Cell`, and why I think the `Cell` around `CellGroupData` is just there for structure.

Comment: I think so too. Ugly anyway. But, assuming that that is true, is there any question left?

Comment: @Rojo yes, for a given `Cell` give me its parent.

Comment: @Rojo Do that, and I think we can answer Mr.Wizard's [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/346/52) on setting a `Context` at a specific level of the hierarchy.

Comment: I have the hunch it's not possible to set that option, just like any other, at the cell group level. But I just saw his question and I think I have an alternative. Check in a min

Comment: @Rojo I don't intend to set it on the parent cell, but on the executing cell. If I can march up the hierarchy, accessing the parent's options as I go, I can use `CellProlog` or `CellEvaluationFunction` to mimic the effect of `CellContext -> CellGrouping` at higher levels in the hierarchy.

Comment: Oh, ok, so something like `SelectionMove[nb, All, CellGroup]; NotebookRead[nb];` and then somehow editing all cells in each group? Yeah, seems ugly

Comment: @Rojo no, something more like: `CellProlog:> Begin[ParentCell[CellContext]]`.

Comment: @Rojo I'd like this to be generic enough that I can specify the option I'm searching for. A good option would be `Recursive -> True` which can return all of the tree, or just the first not set, depending on what you want, likely another option. :)

Comment: The thing is that we fall back to the part where cell groups don't have options, right?

Comment: Is what you want just a matter of having `CellContext->CellGroup` at a higher level of cell group?  If so, then perhaps you might find it easier to change the `CellGroupingRules` on the relevant styles to confine the context the way you want.  The `CellGroup` setting stops at cells with grouping higher than "InputGrouping".  So, for example, I tried setting the Subsubsection style to `CellGroupingRules->{-10, "InputGrouping"}` in a private stylesheet, and `$Context` now spans Subsubsection cells in that notebook.

Comment: @JohnFultz, I'm not sure I understood, in my tests that's also changing the actual grouping of the subsection cells; I couldn't, with that `"InputGrouping"`, to get a Subsubsection automatically grouping as it would with "SectionGrouping". By the way, you know if there is a way to get `CurrentValue[{"CounterValue", "someCounter"}]` to work? Or some way to programatically get the counter value at the point in the notebook where it's being evaluated? (sorry about mistyping your name, I do that a lot, nothing personal hehe )

Comment: @JohnFultz that destroys the grouping which is what I would like to preserve. Also, while my immediate purpose is solve Mr.Wizard's question, my question is more general than that. Having a cell able to tell where it lies in the hierarchy is potentially very powerful.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way that seems to work.

```
parentcell[] := Module[{cellstyle, nb},
  nb = EvaluationNotebook[];
  SelectionMove[nb, All, EvaluationCell]; 
  firstcell[nb];       
  cellstyle = NotebookRead[nb][[2]];

  (* input cell may be grouped with output cell, ignore as parent *)
  If[cellstyle == "Input",
    SelectionMove[nb, All, CellGroup];
    firstcell[nb]
  ]
]
```

where `firstcell` goes to the first cell of the cellgroup

```
firstcell[nb_] := (SelectionMove[nb, All, CellGroup];
  SelectionMove[nb, Before, CellGroup];
  SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell])
```

Since `parentcell` simply sets the notebook selection to the desired cell, one can access it's options using `CurrentValue`, e.g.:

```
parentcell[]; 
CurrentValue[NotebookSelection[EvaluationNotebook[]], CellTags]
```

This function can also be modified to go up until it hits a specified level in the cell grouping hierarchy (e.g., "Section"). This version currently does not terminate unless it finds a cell with the specified style.

```
parentcell[style_String] := Module[{nb},
  nb = EvaluationNotebook[];
  SelectionMove[nb, All, EvaluationCell]; 
  firstcell[nb];

  While[NotebookRead[nb][[2]] =!= style,
   SelectionMove[nb, All, CellGroup];
   firstcell[nb]
  ]
]
```

Finally, these functions have slightly strange behavior when used in cells with no hierarchy (except in/out grouping). The selection will end up either at the input cell or the first cell in the notebook.