# Setting the context automatically based on section

Tags: front-end, contexts

Suppose I have a task that keeps things organized using contexts, so:

```
windowLength = 10;
Begin["chocolate`"];
data = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 100];
ListPlot[MovingAverage[data, windowLength]]
End[]
Begin["vanilla`"];
data = RandomReal[StudentTDistribution[1], 100];
ListPlot[MovingAverage[data, windowLength]]
End[]
```

Now, if I want to go back and do something in the `chocolate` context, I have to remember to re-run the line that enters that context or things can get very confusing and mistakes can easily be made.

It would be really neat to instead use wiggle-4 to create a Section called "Chocolate" and for everything in that section to run in the `chocolate` context. Is there a way to set the context automatically based on the section of the notebook a cell is in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [CellContext](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellContext.html):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The below dialog box can be found in Format -> Option Inspector or Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Open Option Inspector.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When using custom `CellContext` you will need to use `` Global` `` to access global symbols, for example:

```
data = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 100];
ListPlot[MovingAverage[data, Global`windowLength]]
```

If you are hoping to do this automatically for each Section, that functionality does not yet appear to be present (outside of running a script to operate on the Notebook expression to apply these settings).  See my own question:

[Context unique to each group at a specified level](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/346/121)

Also see:

[Is there a way to separate variables between multiple notebooks?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/853/121)