# ClearAll just for current notebook

Tags: notebooks, clear

So in my search to fine tune *Mathematica* to what works for me, I found a nice setting that helps separate variable declaration between notebooks. Under Global Preferences, searching for CellContext and changing from "Global'*" to Notebook does this.  Sweet, but now I am having trouble clearing all the variables.  `ClearAll["Global```*"]` no longer works, and so I figured, since that's the setting I changed, maybe it would now be `ClearAll[Notebook]`. However, this doesn't work either and warns that `Notebook` is protected.

Maybe there is a better method of operation instead of the path I'm attempting to go down.  I use *Mathematica* to do all of my Physics homework in; between each problem I usually do a `ClearAll` so I'm not contaminating possible variables between problems with wrong values.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6539/109) may help too

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do

```
ClearAll[Evaluate[$Context <> "*"]]
```

Or switch the context to be unique to each group of cells.¸

[image: Example menu setting]

Depending on your needs you can also use `Quit[]`, which will terminate the kernel, therbye clearing everything.