# How is CellContext->CellGroup supposed to work?

Tags: programming, front-end, cells, contexts

After reading the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellContext.html) on the subject, I still cannot get `CellContext->CellGroup` to work.

Here's a simple example.  (Unfortunately, I cannot easily show cell grouping, so I'll just have to describe the steps verbally as clearly as possible.)

First I evaluate this (which succeeds):

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellContext -> CellGroup];
```

Then, I create two empty input cells, and group them (right-click->Group Cells).

Next, I type (but do not yet evaluate) the following two expressions into these two (now grouped) cells (one expression per cell):

```
foo = {};  (* first grouped cell *)
```

```
AppendTo[foo, 1];  (* second grouped cell *)
```

*Presumably these two cells now share the same context.*  This will turn out to be wrong.

(FWIW, note that these cells produce no output.)

Lastly, I select the group and evaluate its contents (with shift-enter).  The evaluation of the second cell fails with the following error:

```
AppendTo::rvalue: foo is not a variable with a value, so its value cannot be changed. >>
```

---

**What am I doing wrong?  Is this a bug or a feature?**

---

Here's another, even simpler example.  I proceed as before, except that this time both cells in the group contain the same expression:

```
$Context
```

(NB: no trailing semicolon!)

Now, when I evaluate the group, the output shows that the two grouped cells have different contexts:

```
(* Cell$$17872` *)
```

```
(* Cell$$17874` *)
```

One possible clue to what may be going on is the fact that when I evaluate the last pair of grouped cells, the bracket grouping the two cells disappears.  What's left are 4 *ungrouped* brackets, two for the original input cells, alternating with their respective output cells.  If I delete the output cells, the grouping bracket reappears.  This may be a red herring, since, after all, in my previous example there was no output, and yet the two grouped cells behaved as if their contexts were different.

Comment: It seems that it only refers to cells automatically grouped in a hierarchical way based on their styles (section etc.). :-/ I'd ask Wolfram.

Comment: sort of related: [(346)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/346/121)