# Reference to multiple stylesheets

Tags: stylesheet, inheritance

I need to set `StyleDefinitions` for a notebook in such manner so I can provide references to multiple stylesheets:

```
SetOptions[
 EvaluationNotebook[],
  StyleDefinitions->Notebook[{
   Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Stylesheet1.nb"]],
   Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Stylesheet2.nb"]]
}]
]
```

This code won't work. Only the first one will be taken into account.

#### Requirements:

1. I **can't use explicit `StyleDefinitions`**. So importing + merging those styles won't help me because there are going to be many notebooks depending on them and I don't want to update all of them when I change any stylesheet.
2. I **can't use common setup that stylesheets are joined *step by step***. E.g. `EvaluationNotebook[]` style points to `"Stylesheet1"` which contains reference to `"Stylesheet2"` etc.

   It won't work because I want sometimes to replace `"Stylesheet2"` with `"Stylesheet2b"` etc. Would have to have `"Stylesheet1"` and `"Stylesheet1a"` to keep the whole chain. At the end I'd have to have multiple "top level" stylesheets for all those possible combinations.

#### Toys:

```
{style1, style2} = Notebook[{Cell[StyleData["Input"], #]}] & /@ {
    CellFrame -> True,
    CellFrameColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]};

{path1, path2, path3} = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, #}] & /@ 
    {"Style1.nb",  "Style2.nb", "Style3.nb"};

MapThread[ Export,  {  {path1, path2},  {style1, style2}   }   ]
```

Additional stylesheet created as described in 2.:

```
Export[
 path3,
 Insert[
   style1,
   Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> path2]],
   {1, 1}]
 ]
```

And I would like

```
CreateDocument[{Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"1", "+", "1"}]], "Input"]},
 StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{
       Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->path1]],
       Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->path2]]
    }]
 ]
```

gets red frame too, just like:

```
CreateDocument[{Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"1", "+", "1"}]], "Input"]},
 StyleDefinitions -> path3
 ]
```

Comment: You reject the two natural approaches for doing something like this so I think that unless I am mistaken or someone can demonstrate an undocumented method you are really asking for a new feature implementation.  It would be *so simple* if `StyleDefinitions` were to accept a list in order of precedence, for example.  I hope your "feature request" can be implemented sooner than [mine](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/346/121) as I am still waiting.

Comment: "natural is what I need" -- ah, we all believe that. don't we?

Comment: How do expect your multiple inheritance from two stylesheets to resolve conflicts? Multiple inheritance always causes problems.

Comment: @m_goldberg Couldn't it be done the same way it is with linked stylesheets now, only the link structure is specified in a single list for `StyleDefinitions`?

Comment: @Kuba I guess "natural" here means the two ideas I would have suggested had you left the bulleted points out of the question, as they also occurred to you too obviously.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Using specification order to resolve conflicts is a common and IMO semi-successful way to do it. The only object-oriented language that gets multiple inheritance right (again IMO) is Eiffel, which lets the programmer resolve conflicts on a case-by-case basis if the default resolution is unsatisfactory. However, I don't see anything as sophisticated as that being implemented in _Mathematica_ for something that would be used by few users (again IMO) .

Comment: @m_goldberg as pointed out by Mr.Wizard, I don't need anything new really. Or "natural" which is, I agree with you, subjective. You can have a "a ladder" of stylesheets which handles conflicts by overwriting duplicates. But this built has limitations I've describied. My whish allows you more and needs from system nothing that isn't there already. The only thing that's missing is an "API".

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ok, if natural = obviously-available then I agree :) (deleting that comment)

Comment: To close voters, I don't need the exact syntax. I need such behaviour so maybe there is a valid workflow I'm missing. If not, please post a comment why do you think so.

Comment: The multiple inheritance problem is not to be dismissed.  Styles can be "re-rooted" (effectively told to ignore inheritance) by using `StyleData[name, StyleDefinitions->None]`.  So, let's assume you have multiple stylesheets which inherit from Core.nb.  Each one of them defines a new "Input" style.  Some re-root "Input" and others don't.  What to do?  Also, the multiple inheritance problem introduces serious performance issues...(continued)

Comment: If I have two versions of "Title" inherited from different stylesheets and they define `FontColor` differently, it is no longer acceptable for me to just take the first one.  I must figure out *where* the information came from for each style.  If both stylesheets inherit from Default.nb, but only the second stylesheet overrides Default.nb's version of FontColor, then I must choose the second.  If only the first overrides, then I must choose the first.  This necessity to not just track option settings, but the precise provenance of each and every option setting is expensive...(continued)

Comment: ...and these particular computations, although we cache them as much as possible, are one of the most expensive computations in the system.  Not to mention the amount of effort to implement which, as has been pointed out in this thread, has a very low payoff because very few people would ever use this feature.

Comment: That having been said, your statement that multiple stylesheets "don't work" is not strictly true. They don't work for your purposes. But they *do* work.  You can use multiple `StyleData[StyleDefinition->...]` cells to mix in new styles.  So if, in your example, `"StyleSheet2.nb"` has styles which don't exist in `"StyleSheet1.nb"`, then they will be amalgamated together in your new stylesheet.  So it does do *something*, just not what you were hoping for.  Sorry for the multiple commenting, but I don't feel like I'm actually answering your question. Unless you'd accept "no" as an answer. :)

Comment: @JohnFultz Thanks a lot for your input. I think those troubles could be avoided if we put two requirements: list of paths is considered ordered and each linked stylesheed is considered one level, e.g. if it includes deeper linkes, they will be droped. What do you think about that?

Comment: @JohnFultz I really think you should post those comments as an answer, verbatim even.  And thanks for posting, as always!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A copy of [John Fultz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/309/john-fultz)'s comments [posted](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86848/reference-to-multiple-stylesheets/87370#comment236550_86848) June 26, 2015 preserved for enduring reference:

> The multiple inheritance problem is not to be dismissed.  Styles can
>   be "re-rooted" (effectively told to ignore inheritance) by using
>   `StyleData[name, StyleDefinitions->None]`.  So, let's assume you have
>   multiple stylesheets which inherit from Core.nb.  Each one of them
>   defines a new "Input" style.  Some re-root "Input" and others don't. 
>   What to do?  Also, the multiple inheritance problem introduces serious
>   performance issues.
>
> If I have two versions of "Title" inherited from different stylesheets
>   and they define `FontColor` differently, it is no longer acceptable
>   for me to just take the first one.  I must figure out *where* the
>   information came from for each style.  If both stylesheets inherit
>   from Default.nb, but only the second stylesheet overrides Default.nb's
>   version of FontColor, then I must choose the second.  If only the
>   first overrides, then I must choose the first.  This necessity to not
>   just track option settings, but the precise provenance of each and
>   every option setting is expensive and these particular computations,
>   although we cache them as much as possible, are one of the most
>   expensive computations in the system.  Not to mention the amount of
>   effort to implement which, as has been pointed out in this thread, has
>   a very low payoff because very few people would ever use this feature.
>
> That having been said, your statement that multiple stylesheets "don't
>   work" is not strictly true. They don't work for your purposes. But
>   they *do* work.  You can use multiple
>   `StyleData[StyleDefinition->...]` cells to mix in new styles.  So if,
>   in your example, `"StyleSheet2.nb"` has styles which don't exist in
>   `"StyleSheet1.nb"`, then they will be amalgamated together in your new
>   stylesheet.  So it does do *something*, just not what you were hoping
>   for.  Sorry for the multiple commenting, but I don't feel like I'm
>   actually answering your question. Unless you'd accept "no" as an
>   answer. :)

Comment: Just a comment to the last section. That's not true for built-in styles like `Input/Output`, maybe because we are already inheriting from `$FrontEnd` (are we? what does it mean? [closely related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87184/5478)),

Comment: @Kuba, my last paragraph indicates that multiple stylesheets lets you mix in "new styles". What I mean by this is stylenames which have not been previously defined. Input/Output are defined in Core.nb, which is ultimately inherited by nearly every stylesheet in the system. Not many styles you've heard of get defined in Core.nb because we don't want to insert hard-coded stylenames into effectively every stylesheet. So, you won't find Section or Title or Code, for example. But Input and Output are so universal to the way the system works, it seemed better just to put them in Core.nb.

Comment: @JohnFultz yes, now I see I get your comment wrong. I will try to think about this whole system and my doubts again as soon as I can. Thanks for your input here and in the linked topic.