# Stylesheet Directives for DisplayFormular overwritten?

Tags: front-end, style, stylesheet, fonts, text-formatting

I'm trying to change the font of DisplayFormula, DisplayFormulaNumbered and InlineFormula in my stylesheet. So in the options inspector of the stylesheet under `FormatingOptions->FontOptions` I changed FontFamily to "Baskerville". Every other settings are left unchanged for now. I then saved the stylesheet, opened a new notebook and applied that stylesheet to the new notebook. After that, i created a new DisplayFormula cell. But the new font is not applied. When i open the options inspector of the new cell, under `FormatingOptions->FontOptions->FontFamily` it says

```
Dynamic[AbsoluteCurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], {StyleHints, "CodeFont"}]]
```

, and not "Baskerville". If i want to change the font, i manually have to do that for every cell.

Changing fonts in the stylesheet works perfectly fine for all other cell types. Why are my settings overwritten in this case?

@Kuba had the same question here:

[Why does Mathematica ignore my stylesheet for DisplayFormulaNumbered cells?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165455/why-does-mathematica-ignore-my-stylesheet-for-displayformulanumbered-cells)

He suggests that the cell style should be declared for every screen environment. But

```
Cell[StyleData["DisplayFormula","Working"],FontFamily->"Baskerville",FontSize->14,PrivateFontOptions->{"FontPostScriptName"->"Automatic"}]
```

yields the same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards, Fabian.

Comment: Did you really saved the stylesheets? They are `Savable -> False` by default and thus need some extra work to save it.