# How to control indentation of a cell relative to it's parent?

Tags: cells, stylesheet, style

Is there a stylesheet property that can be set to control the extra level of indentation of a cell in its group (I don't want to specify absolute CellMargins)?

Carl suggests in the comments to use this in the stylesheet:

```
Cell[StyleData["Item"], CellMargins -> {{Inherited + 20, 10}, {10, 5}}]
```

which yields:

[image]

But this looks bad, I'd like them to be indented left-horizontally flush to their cell group's parent cell, plus a fixed about. Would look approximately like this (I used the ruler toolbar):

[image]

Comment: Something like: `CellMargins -> {{Inherited + 10, 10}, {10, 5}}`?

Comment: @CarlWoll That's only for style inheritance - not cell groups in general, or am I wrong about that?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks, do my edits clear it up?

Comment: I'm probably just being a dunce (again) but I'm still not certain I understand.  Perhaps you could manually edit the CellMargins for your example to show what your desired format would look like?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Mr.Wizard ain't no dunce!

Comment: Could it be that stylesheets aren't expressive enough to deal with such a constraint? I wish that the documentation for `Inherited` was clearer about use cases involving cell groups and in stylesheets.

Comment: Afaic you can not. Take a look at subitemparagraph and friends, they have those vales hardcoded. P.s. this was asked before I think.

Comment: In a vague tangential way this is related to a question of my own: [(346)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/346/121)